# PHP mysqli->prepare returning nothing

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to use a mysqli connection to retrieve rows from my database however I continue to receive a 500 internal server error no matter what I try.

```
$getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = ? AND member_id > 0";
$getUserStatement = $mysqli_conn->prepare($getUserQuery);
$getUserStatement->bind_param("s", $name);
```

$mysqli_conn->ping() results in a value of true so I know there's no issue with the database connection. var_dump($getUserStatement) results in bool(false) so there's some issue with the prepare. Whole code:

```
$user_dirty = $_GET['u'];
$pass_dirty = $_GET['p'];

$getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = ? AND member_id > 0";
$getUserStatement = $mysqli_conn->prepare($getUserQuery);

if ($getUserStatement) {
    echo($getUserStatement);
} else {
    echo("not good");
}

$getUserStatement->bind_param("s", $user_dirty);
$getUserStatement->execute();
$getUserResult = $getUserStatement->get_result();
```

And how I create my DB connection:

```
$mysql_host = "host";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$mysql_database = "db";

$mysqli_conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
```

Comment: You need  to bind params like this 
`$getUserStatement = $mysqli_conn->prepare($getUserQuery); $getUserStatement ->bind_param('s', $yoname); $getUserStatement ->execute();`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing after this. I'll update the post with a little more code.

Comment: @Mihai I think he get false on var_dump because connection is lost or something like that, because statment must be resource even before he sets parameters

Comment: @user2962442 I attempted a ping after the prepare and it returned true so I know the connection is still being maintained.

Comment: @Swizzbeat try ping before prepare, it will reconnect on lost connection

Comment: Dont be shy with code,post your connection and the whole shebang

Comment: @Mihai updated with more code.

Comment: Id the statement failed to prepare then look at `$mysqli_conn->error` and see what the error is.

Comment: @prodigitalson nothing is printed.

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE members` form whatever mysql client you use for administration.

Answer (score 0):

You gets 500 internal error because statement is false probably(https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/2962442 turn on display errors), not resource like it should be, it can be caused by lost connection, try ping or reconnect before prepare.

Example good code:

```
$getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = ? AND member_id > 0";
$getUserStatement = $mysqli_conn->prepare($getUserQuery);
if ($getUserStatement) {
    $getUserStatement->bind_param("s", $name);
} else {
    //statement is false, not good
}
```

and good example of connection part

```
$mysql_host = "host";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$mysql_database = "db";

$mysqli_conn = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);    
if (!$mysqli_conn) {
    //not connected...
}
```

Comment: Tried it but without success. The ping still returns 1 though.

Comment: which DB driver do you use to connect?

Comment: the bind_param returns true however I'm still receiving a 500 internal server error at line 1 of my code and the statement is never executed.

Comment: to execute statement use execute method, 500 error is internal server error, then enable php errors

Comment: display_errors is turned on in my php.ini file however nothings being displayed.

Comment: everything is turned on and nothings being displayed.

Comment: Updated my original post.

Comment: this tells me nothing. is the same file, or do you use include, or what

Comment: I include the database initialization code in an include_once in my user query file.

Comment: without error I cannot tell anything, try to display errors